# PriorityQueue not sorting properly

Tags: java, sorting, priority-queue, comparator

Currently this is my enum (VisitorInfo) class:

```
public enum Ticket{
    NO_TICKET(0), REG_TICKET(1), FAST_TICKET(2);
    private int status;

    Ticket(int status)
    {
        this.status = status;
    }

    int getStatus() {
        return status;
    }
}
```

And this is currently my Queue declaration:

```
    PriorityQueue<VisitorInfo> pq = new PriorityQueue<VisitorInfo>(20, new Comparator<VisitorInfo>() {
        public int compare(VisitorInfo n1, VisitorInfo n2) {
            if (n1.ticket.getStatus() == n2.ticket.getStatus())
                return 0;
            if (n1.ticket.getStatus() > n2.ticket.getStatus())
                return -1;
            return 1;
        }
    });
```

And my main method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FullQueueException {
RideQueue bleh = new RideQueue("hi", 20);

VisitorInfo bleh1 = new VisitorInfo("NO1", VisitorInfo.Ticket.NO_TICKET);
VisitorInfo bleh2 = new VisitorInfo("NO2", VisitorInfo.Ticket.NO_TICKET);
VisitorInfo bleh3 = new VisitorInfo("NO3", VisitorInfo.Ticket.NO_TICKET);
VisitorInfo bleh4 = new VisitorInfo("REG1", VisitorInfo.Ticket.REG_TICKET);
VisitorInfo bleh5 = new VisitorInfo("REG2", VisitorInfo.Ticket.REG_TICKET);
VisitorInfo bleh6 = new VisitorInfo("REG3", VisitorInfo.Ticket.REG_TICKET);
VisitorInfo bleh7 = new VisitorInfo("FAST1", VisitorInfo.Ticket.FAST_TICKET);
VisitorInfo bleh8 = new VisitorInfo("FAST2", VisitorInfo.Ticket.FAST_TICKET);

bleh.pq.add(bleh1);
bleh.pq.add(bleh2);
bleh.pq.add(bleh3);
bleh.pq.add(bleh4);
bleh.pq.add(bleh5);
bleh.pq.add(bleh6);
bleh.pq.add(bleh7);
bleh.pq.add(bleh8);

for (int i = 1; i<9; i++)
{
    System.out.println(bleh.pq.poll().getName());
}



}
```

My output:

```
FAST1
FAST2
REG3
REG2
REG1
NO2
NO1
NO3
```

Why is it not sorting properly?

I'm sorry I forgot to add, Fast should be printing out first, then reg, then no.

Comment: You should tag your question with appropriate language. I'm guessing it's java?

Comment: yeah sorry, updated it

Comment: Why do you think it's not working?

Comment: Because I added in REG1 before REG2 and vice versa, so it should print out as:

FAST1
FAST2
REG1
REG2
REG3
NO1
NO2
NO3

Comment: @AlexanderKhaosGreenstein: Did you read the Javadoc?  "If multiple elements are tied for least value, the head is one of those elements -- ties are broken arbitrarily."  `PriorityQueue` doesn't support keeping insertion order like that.

Comment: Ahh I see, alright, I appreciate the find! I passed over that x.x. I am working with an arraylist now and everything is working fine. I really appreciate it, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want your sort by name or your sort by status? Your Comparator is based upon the status, but you're expecting the order to be by name. N01, N02, N03 are all NO_TICKET with a status of 0. So which one would go first?

Comment: Basically the concept is that firstly, the order that we add the objects is the order they should remain in the queue, second, a Fast ticket has priority over a regular ticket, which has priority over no ticket. As long as the queue retains the order the objects were added, while making sure the higher priority ones are first, then it will be fine. In this instance, I added them in name order, but if I had added say, REG2 before REG1 then it should print REG2 before REG1.

Comment: A `PriorityQueue` doesn't support "the order that we add the objects is the order they should remain in the queue.'

Comment: @AlexanderKhaosGreenstein That clarification is not consistent with what you have stated so far, and makes the question more ambiguous. I'm not sure why the downvote, but look at what Louis Wasserman pointed out in his other answers. You want an order that simply will not happen given your current implementation and expectations.

Comment: I just read what he stated and I understand now. I wasn't aware that it couldn't keep order in cases of ties. Thanks everyone!